# element-attribute-range-query fetching result but element-attribute-value-query is not fetching any result

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I wanted to fetch the document which have the particular element attribute value.

So, I tried the `cts:element-attribute-value-query` but I didn't get any result. But the same element attribute value, I am able to get using `cts:element-attribute-range-query`.

Here the sample snippet used.

```
let $s-query := cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("tit:title"),xs:QName("name"),"=",
"SampleTitle",
("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint"))


let $s-query := cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("tit:title"),xs:QName("name"),
"SampleTitle",
())

return cts:search(fn:doc(),($s-query))
```

The problem with range-query is it needs the range index. I have hundreds of DB's in multiple hosts. I need to create range indexes on each DB.

What could be the problem with attribute-value-query?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MarkLogic database 8.0-3. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue with a couple of research.

Actually the result document is a french language document. It has the structure as follows. This is a sample.

```
<doc xml:lang="fr:CA" xmlns:tit="title">
    <tit:title name="SampleTitle"/>
</doc>
```

The `cts:element-attribute-value-query` is a language dependent query. To get the french language results, then language needs to be mentioned in the option as follows.

```
cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("tit:title"),xs:QName("name"), "SampleTitle",("lang=fr"))
```

But `cts:element-attribute-range-query` don't require the language option.

Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Correct. Range indexes work on exact values, while value queries work on the language specific universal index by default. You could try 'exact' or 'wildcarded' as option to the value-query.

Comment: @grtjn, my document is totally confidential which I am not supposed to get any part. So, I just gave the sample. And I am working on VDI machine and asked this question on another machine. So, when I get the answer, I just typed it. Its a typo.